# Sumar resultados de consulta con group by

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT count(dp.id_dieta) * 
    (select d.dieta from dietas d where d.idDietas = dp.id_dieta) as t
FROM dietaspartes dp 
WHERE dp.id_parte in 
    (SELECT p.idparte as part 
    FROM partes p 
    WHERE p.IDProyecto = 1111)
GROUP BY id_dieta
```

Que me devuelve dos resultados: 50 y 30

Me gustaria modificar dicha consulta para devolver la suma de estos dos valores, pero con la posibilidad de que si son 3 o X, devuelva la suma de esos X valores.

Si englobo con un Sum me dice que hago un uso invalido de group by

Estoy un poco bloqueado con esto,
gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema que te da el sistema del uso invalido del `group by` se debe a que el valor del `group by` debe formar parte de la `select`, en tu caso debes colocar

```
 SELECT id_dieta, 
        SUM(COUNT(dp.id_dieta) * d.dieta) AS t
    FROM dietaspartes dp
        INNER JOIN dietas d ON dp.id_dieta = d.idDietas
    WHERE dp.id_parte in (SELECT p.idparte 
                                FROM partes p 
                                WHERE p.IDProyecto = 1111)   
    GROUP BY id_dieta
```

Comment: podrias ponerme la consulta completa por favor?, ya que no consigo que me funcione

Comment: He editado el codigo propuesto

Answer (score 0):

Al final he conseguido solucionarlo y me queda asi, quizas a alguien le venga bien

```
    SELECT SUM(t)
FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(dp.id_dieta) * (
SELECT d.dieta
FROM dietas d
WHERE d.idDietas = dp.id_dieta) AS t
FROM dietaspartes dp
WHERE dp.id_parte IN 
 (
SELECT p.idparte AS part
FROM partes p
WHERE p.IDProyecto = 1111)
GROUP BY id_dieta) AS tt
```

Comment: tienes 4 SELECT, creo que esto no puede ser una respuesta valida, la opcion de Carmelo se ve mas limpia solo debes analizarla un poco mas , con un inner join y el group by puedes hacerlo